# Richard Goldschmidt's “systemic mutations”?

Tags: evolution, mutations, theoretical-biology

**[TLDR] I dont understand the fault people had/have with Richard Goldscmidt's concept of systemic mutations [/TLDR]**

As a preface, I am a undergrad biology student, so sorry if this is a "Stupid question".

How does Richard Goldschmidt's concept of systemic mutations, reject the classical gene concept, why were biologists so against it?

From what I  understand he used the concept of systemic mutations and developmental macromutations in his lectures to explain how macromutations could cause speciation(macroevolution?). The results of the developmental macromutations, if I understand him correctly would be then the Hopeful Monsters?

And from what I have read on a timeline of his work, systemic mutations describe the "large rearrangments of the chromosome", with a new arrangement meaning a new phenotype?

How is that wrong though? Do chromosomes not have rearrangements via cross over events during meiosis or via transposable elements? Or is he referring to something else, since I understand at the time, meiosis and TE's were not understood well.

The source i was reading from was:
(Richard Goldschmidt: hopeful monsters and other 'heresies' by Michael R. Dietrich) Available from http://www.dartmouth.edu/~dietrich/NRG2003.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His notion of systemic mutations involved the postulation of massive chromosomal rearrangements (not mere recombination/crossing-over) as mediators of speciation in one-step. While whole genome duplications have been shown to induce speciation (see, for example, cryptic speciation in *Hyla versicolor*) they are not large scale rearrangements as he suggested. Additionally, while there is evidence for multiple large scale chromosomal arrangements at once in cancers (Chromothripsis) , there is no evidence of a similar process resulting in immediate reproductive isolation.